# perf_event_open: Including the execution of child process in case of sampling

Tags: linux-kernel, performancecounter, perf

According to [man pages](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/perf_event_open.2.html) to consider the execution of child process when counting for events, `inherit` bit can be set. `inherit` can not be used when using PERF_FORMAT_GROUP. So, how can I include the execution of child process (execution of shell commands with in C source code, for example) so that it can be counted when sampling (PERF_FORMAT_GROUP) using `perf_event_open`

if PERF_FORMAT_GROUP is not specified, does this indicate that for each recorded sample, each sample record will include `struct read_format` equal to the number of events or a sample will be recorded for each event alone.

Comment: Please clarify what part of your question is still unanswered. Also provide the exact command and output of `perf` (there are many perf commands). Also provide a [mcve] of the code using `perf_event_open` and it's output.

Comment: Please see question re-edit....

Answer (score 1):

If you *need* to use `PERF_FORMAT_GROUP`, and that doesn't work with the built-in `inherit`, then you have to keep track of the children yourself. You can do that by using `ptrace` and then setup `perf_event_open` for all child tasks. Then you also have to merge the samples from all event file descriptors.

Edit:
Without `PERF_FORMAT_GROUP`, the internal sampling recording is not at the same time. You could of course just setup *counting events* (instead of a *sampling events*), and read them at the same time in regular intervals from userspace.

Comment: If `PERF_FORMAT_GROUP`is not used, will different events still be recorded at the same time? Also, at this case, how do you think the readings will be stored, If I can't read them at the same time?
I have tried to investigate this when setting the `inherit` bit without using `PERF_FORMAT_GROUP` and using `PERF_FORMAT_ID`, for some reason mmap fails with invalid arguments error. mmap has been called as the following:
`mmap(NULL, 4096*3, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);`
What do you think could be the possible reasons?

Comment: @user3527764 See my edit. For a specific code error it is probably best to open a new question, make sure to include an [mcve].